# NSMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString Warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got an RSS parser method and I need to remove whitespace and other nonsense from my extracted html summary. I've got a NSMutableString type 'currentSummary'. When I call:

```
currentSummary = [currentSummary 
        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Xcode tells me "warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type"

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If `currentSummary` is already a NSMutableString you shouldn't attempt to assign a regular NSString (the result of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`) to it.

Instead use the mutable equivalent `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`, or add a call to `mutableCopy` before the assignment:

```
// Either
[currentSummary replaceOccurencesOfString:@"\n" 
                               withString:@"" 
                                  options:NULL
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [receiver length])];

// Or
currentSummary = [[currentSummary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                            withString:@""]
                  mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 3):

This works great for nested elements as well of course:

****Edited****

```
// Get the JSON feed from site
myRawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
            URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/mobile_list.json"] 
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Make the content something we can use in fast enumeration
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary * myParsedJson = [parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:NULL];
[myRawJson release];
allLetterContents = [myParsedJson objectForKey:@"nodes"];

    // Create arrays just for the title and Nid items
    self.contentTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSMutableDictionary * key in myArr) {
        NSDictionary *node = [key objectForKey:@"node"];
        NSMutableString *savedContentTitle = [node objectForKey:@"title"];        

        // Add each Title and Nid to specific arrays
        //[self.contentTitleArray addObject:contentTitle];

        //change each item with &amp; to &
        [self.contentTitleArray addObject:[[savedContentTitle      
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" 
                                withString:@"&"] 
                                mutableCopy]];

    }
```

The code below, as shown in the use-case above might be helpful.

```
[self.contentTitleArray addObject:[[contentTitle 
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" 
                                    withString:@"&"] 
                                    mutableCopy]];
```

Comment: Hi, Pat! I'm not sure your answer really answers the question asked. I'd also recommend that instead of explaining "contentTitleArray is..." you could just write some example code. You know, the minimum required so that both you and the person asking the question have a common basis on which to understand what each of you means. Thank you for taking the time to write an answer, and good luck on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Okay, I've gone ahead and added my use-case. Hopefully this will be helpful for passers-by.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means you dropped the asterisks in the definition of (in this case) currentSummary.

So you most likely have:

```
NSMutableString currentSummary;
```

when you need:

```
NSMutableString *currentSummary;
```

In the first case, since Objective-C classes are defined in type structures, the complier thinks your trying to assign a NSString to a struct.

I make this typo on a distressingly regular basis.