# URL Encoding a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, url

i am receiving a json data object and then i extract a string from it

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:nil];
NSString *country=jsonDictionary[@"address"][@"country"];
```

then i try to make the string suitable to be used in a URL

```
NSString *newCountryString = [country stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "  
   withString:@"%%20"];
```

but it is not working

if i hard coded the newCountryString it would work, why is that ?

Comment: What you need? what you got?

Comment: This questions is misleading: it doesn't have anything to do with _JSON parsing_, and only remotely with JSON. The questions is rather how to compose a valid URL from strings.

Comment: why this is off-topic ???

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use This -

```
NSString *newCountryString = [country stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This code will return a representation of the receiver using a given encoding to determine the percent escapes necessary to convert the receiver into a legal URL string.

for more details:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415058-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusin

**Edit -** 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is deprecated in iOS 9. Use following instead

```
[country stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]
```

**Swift 3 -**

```
country.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

for more details:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc

Comment: Thanks, mate. This worked out fine.

Comment: it work like a magic right now :)

i have a url that have an 


٢٠١٧-٠٤-٠١١٠:٤٤:١٦.jpg



after encoding it turn to be                                                                                                    


%D9%A2%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A7-%D9%A0%D9%A4-%D9%A0%D9%A1%D9%A1%D9%A0:%D9%A4%D9%A4:%D9%A1%D9%A6.jpg

Answer (score 13):

As variant you can use method below:

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodeStringFromString:(NSString *)string
{
 static CFStringRef charset = CFSTR("!@#$%&*()+'\";:=,/?[] ");
 CFStringRef str = (__bridge CFStringRef)string;
 CFStringEncoding encoding = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
 return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, str, NULL, charset, encoding));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSSString method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding should help you. Also see [How to prepare an NSURL from an NSString continaing international characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418754/how-to-prepare-an-nsurl-from-an-nsstring-continaing-international-characters)

Comment: Be aware that this method doesn't not encode every special character, see : http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/ for more informations

Comment: The truth is, _each component_ of a URL may require a (slightly) different percent encoding, or non at all. That is, composing a URL from (unencoded) strings is actually much more complex than it really should.

Comment: @Volker stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is unreliable, for example it converts "New Zealand" to "New2ealand"

Answer (score -2):

I think you should remove one % like below

```
NSString *newCountryString = [country stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

for more

[NSMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647292/nsmutablestring-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstring-warning)