# Make a clickable link in an NSAttributedString for a UITextView

Tags: ios, hyperlink, character-encoding, urlencode, nsmutablestring

I made a clickable link. My code:

```
NSString *textBlah = @"blah bleh bluh blih....";

    - (void)hyperLinkAndColor:(NSString*)name withAttribute:(NSMutableAttributedString*)attributedText{

        if ([textBlah rangeOfString:name].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSRange rangeName = [textInformation rangeOfString:name];
            if ([name rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
                name = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
            }

            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"linktink://?name=%@", name]];
            [attributedText beginEditing];
            [attributedText addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[url absoluteString] range:rangeName];
            [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:rangeName];
            [attributedText endEditing];
        }
    }
```

It works fine. But i get one issue. When 'name' is 您好 or হ্যালো or héllò..., url always return nil.How to detect 您好 or হ্যালো ... and make clickable on it?

Comment: try this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403323/url-encoding-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to URL Encode the string so that unicode characters won't create an issue.

```
NSString *textBlah = @"blah bleh bluh blih....";

- (void)hyperLinkAndColor:(NSString*)name withAttribute:(NSMutableAttributedString*)attributedText{

    if ([textBlah rangeOfString:name].location != NSNotFound) {

        NSRange rangeName = [textInformation rangeOfString:name];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"linktink://?name=%@", name];

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [attributedText beginEditing];
        [attributedText addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[url absoluteString] range:rangeName];
        [attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor orangeColor] range:rangeName];
        [attributedText endEditing];
    }
}
```