# Objective-C URL string contains single percent sign

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, escaping, sign, percent-encoding

I have a string which ends with percent sign(%),

this string is prepared for an URL request as a parameter:

```
NSString *parameter = @"/param=%";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.whatev%@",parameter]]];
```

The request returns `nil`.

I've tried:

```
NSString *parameter = @"/param=\uFF05";
//request returns nil
```

and

```
NSString *parameter =  @"/param=%";
NSString *newParameter = [parameter stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//request returns /param=%25 ...where does 25 come from?!
```

How could I have only one % converted to a request url?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403323/url-encoding-a-string/21404487#21404487

Comment: %25 is for %... That is because of Encoding... Like space is converted to %20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent sign has a special purpose in URL's and is used to encode special characters of all kinds. For example a space ( ) is %20 and the percent sign itself is %25.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

The last one should be correct, I assume you have problems using it as a request?

Comment: u're right the last works fine ! I was just confused about the 25 and forgot to give it a try lol...

Answer (score 0):

escape sequence for `%` is `%%`, so `@"/param=%%"` should solve the problem