# How to pass GET request for PayTm transaction in ios Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, get, paytm

I am integrating **PayTm** with my app and I want to pass the **parameters** using **GET** method.

My code is as follows:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/TXNSTATUS?JsonData={%22MID%22:%22%@%22,%22ORDERID%22:%22a84afd6c-0e54-42df-b29a-2b057f9e7c53%22}",MIDValue];
```

*where **MIDValue** is a string.*

When I use this code I'm getting error message.

Please give a suggestion to remove the error.

Thank You

Comment: What error message?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your variable **MIDValue** contains space and/or &.
You first have to encode it as URL and then pass it as parameter.

[Visit this for details, I guess this is what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21404487/5173593)

```
NSString *newParam = [MIDValue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/TXNSTATUS?JsonData={%22MID%22:%22%@%22,%22ORDERID%22:%22a84afd6c-0e54-42df-b29a-2b057f9e7c53%22}", newParam];
```