# stringByReplacingOccourencesOfString with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

I get from a XML-file the following text:

`"Weekly menus from December 21<sup>st</sup> till 28<sup>th</sup>"` and want them to be shown as: "Weekly menus from December 21<sup>st</sup> till 28<sup>th</sup>"

The -Tags are because the XML-file is used for html and iOS. Now I want to "shift" the st/nd/rd/th in the date and made the following code:

```
NSString *basicString = dieMenueDaten.SubtitelE;

NSDictionary *attribute = @{(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName: @1 };
NSMutableAttributedString *subStringTh = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"th" attributes:attribute];
NSMutableAttributedString *newSubtitleE = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:basicString];
NSMutableAttributedString *replaceTh = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"<sup>th</sup>"];

NSRange laenge = NSMakeRange(0, basicString.length);

newSubtitleE = [[newSubtitleE mutableString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:replaceTh withString:subStringTh options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:laenge];
```

Doing this I get

> incompatible pointers type sending 'NSMutableAttributedString *' to parameter of type 'NSString *_Nonnull'

and

> incompatible pointers type assigning to 'NSMutableAttributedString *' from 'NSString *'

What must I do to avoid the error-messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString Warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647292/nsmutablestring-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstring-warning)

Comment: similar to that duplicate, but you're trying to mix mutable and immutable attributed and plain strings, not just mutable and immutable plain strings...

Comment: Find all the ranges, and use `replaceCharactersInRange: withAttributedString:` instead?

Answer (score 0):

From the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:)

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target
                                    withString:(NSString *)replacement
                                       options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options
                                         range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

This method takes 2 `NSString` parameters for the target and replacement, not two NSMutableAttributedString parameters.

You could additionally try `replaceTh.string` and `subStringTh.string` to get the `NSString` property of each `NSMutableAttributedString` you've provided.

Your second warning is related, since the above method returns a `NSString`, not an `NSMutableAttributedString`, which you've declared `newSubtitleE` as such.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I found a hint in here where the "stringByReplacing... with options and range was used with the attributedStrings. I looked for another solution.

Comment: Maybe you were looking for the `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString` method as found in `NSMutableArributedString` reference?  Use the docs and you won't have to guess at what methods are available.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, due to the quick hints I changed it as followed (with good description here in so):

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)attributedSubTitleString:(NSString *)string;
{
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
UIFont *smallFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0f];

[attString beginEditing];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"th"]];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"th" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"th"]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"th" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"st"]];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"st" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"st"]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"st" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"nd"]];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"nd" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"nd"]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"nd" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];

[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"rd"]];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:[string rangeOfString:@"rd" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"rd"]];
[attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:[string rangeOfString:@"rd" options:NSBackwardsSearch]];

[attString endEditing];
return attString;
}
```

and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *basicString = dieMenueDaten.SubtitelE;

basicString = [basicString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<sup>" withString:@""];
basicString = [basicString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</sup>" withString:@""];

NSMutableAttributedString *newSubtitleE = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:basicString];

newSubtitleE = [self attributedSubTitleString:basicString];
....
        cell.MenueTitel.text = dieMenueDaten.TitelE;
        cell.MenueSubtitel.attributedText = newSubtitleE;
```

Works perfect for me.

Answer (score -1):

Check this repository: [DecodeHTML.swift](https://github.com/TheFlow95/DecodeHTML.swift)